# Transaction handling multi-tier application

Tags: java, .net, distributed-transactions

Is there a possibility having transactions across multiple systems?

For exeample:

layer 1 - exposes web services (Deployed to weblogic)
layer 2 - .NET front end (Deployed to IIS)

Can we have transaction commit or rollback for multiple web service calls initiated from .NET?

If so, can someone point me any resource or document?  And is there any special requirement for each of the layer comply to participate in transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  WCF allows for the consumption of web services that utilize the [WS-Atomic Transaction](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wsat/2006/06) standard, assuming you have [`System.Transactions.TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) available in your .NET client (Silverlight, for example, does not have this).

There is an excellent [example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wsat_transactions.aspx) that shows both how to produce and consume transaction web services in .NET using `TransactionScope`.

Answer (score 0):

[casperOne's mention of `TransactionScope`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140358/transaction-handling-multi-tier-application/7141274#7141274) is an excellent solution if it is available in your scenario. I have fallen in love with the simplicity and power it brings to the table.

However, I note that you have a Java tag and mention Weblogic as the web service tier, so the [`TransactionScopeRequired` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.transactionscoperequired.aspx) would have to be implemented via WS-AT (Web Services Atomic Transaction) or a similar transcriptional protocol.

See here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/cjta_wstran.html

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely possible, but could prove to be harrier than you'd think. You need control to modify the execution environment of those web services to augment them such that they can consume the WS-AT headers. In addition as with any distributed transaction environment you probably will incur a performance increase because of the substantial administrative overhead.

SOA-WORLD had some great articles that explain Web Service transactions and all the related OASIS standards. Here is the one on [WS-Coordination](http://soa.sys-con.com/node/39751) if I can find the rest I'll add them.